# How can I mock a static json file differently for tests?

Tags: json, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a .json file that contains `{ apiUrl: '#{placeholder}' }` that I'm using for my Octopus deployments.

My service that uses the .json file:

```
import config from '../../configuration/appconfig.json'

function appConfigService() {
    const { apiUrl } = config

    return {
        apiUrl: `${
            apiUrl === '#{placeholder}' ? 'http://localhost:57567' : apiUrl
        }/api/`
    }
}

export default appConfigService
```

The issue I'm running into is testing both scenarios (in the same .test file). If I go the

`/__mocks__/appconfigMock.js` route

or the

`jest.mock('../../configuration/appconfig.json', () => ({ 
    apiUrl: 'https://a-legit-url.com' 
}))` route,

the value is the same for all tests. I can't mock within a single test as it doesn't work for an import. I can't unmock within a single test either. The only solution I can find is to split the tests into two files (ridiculous) and  mock them separately.

I've tried

```
jest.resetModules()
jest.unmock('../../configuration/appconfig.json')
```

within the test that I don't want to use the mock and it still uses the mock.

Is this something that's just not possible for a static json file? Really seems like it should be.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?